# How can I show an image on another page by clicking a button and saving it?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is like the save button on Instagram "the bookmark". so when I click on the button the image will display on another page and also it will be saved. I have the image on a page named menu what I want is when I click on the button the image will stay in the menu and when I open the folder page (the other page that will contain the image) I find the image.

```html
<section id="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 2px;">
    <div id="foresult" class="col-sm-3 col-over">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/cake7.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="overlay left-overlay">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
          <script src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/xdjxvujz.js"></script>

          <lord-icon src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/wurbjznp.json" trigger="loop" delay="1000" colors="primary:#121331" style="width:32px;height:32px">
          </lord-icon>
        </a>
      </div>
```